# numpy in call method: how to run without eager execution?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, autoencoder

I wrote an implementation of a feedback recurrent autoencoder in Keras. The key difference to a regular autoencoder is, that the decoded output is fed back to the input layers of both, encoder and decoder, of the autoencoder and there merged with the current new input of the autoencoder. Currently, my code looks like this

```
     class Autoencoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim, shape):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.shape = shape
    self.ht    = 2
    self.buffer= np.repeat(np.zeros(shape,dtype=np.float32), repeats=self.ht, axis=1)
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(np.round(shape[0]*shape[1]*1.5), activation='swish'),
      layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='swish'),
      
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(np.round(shape[0]*shape[1]*1.5), activation='swish'),
      layers.Dense(tf.math.reduce_prod(shape), activation='sigmoid'),
      layers.Reshape(shape)
    ])
    
  def update_buffer(self, new_element):
    n = self.shape[1] 
    self.buffer[:, n:] = self.buffer[:, :-n]
    self.buffer[:, :n] = new_element
 

  def call(self, x):
    decoded = [None] * x.shape[0] 
    for i in range(0, x.shape[0]):
        buffer_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.buffer)
        xin     = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat((x[i,:,:], buffer_tensor), axis=1), axis=0)
        encoded = self.encoder(xin)
        buffer_reshaped = tf.reshape(buffer_tensor, [1,self.buffer.shape[0]*self.buffer.shape[1]])
        decin = tf.concat([encoded, buffer_reshaped], axis=1)
        y = self.decoder(decin)
        decoded[i] = y
        
        self.update_buffer(tf.squeeze(y))

    out = tf.squeeze(tf.convert_to_tensor(decoded))            
    return out
```

and runs fine in eager execution mode. However, because training is pretty slow, I'd like to see the performance without eager execution. Unfortunately, then the training immediately fails, because I use numpy function calls: I receive the error

> ```
>     NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (autoencoder_36/Squeeze:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
> ```

due to the line
       `self.update_buffer(tf.squeeze(y))`
and the corresponding method. How do I implement a buffer like mine in tensorflow so that I can avoid getting this error? The key issue is the assignment

> ```
> self.buffer[:, :n] = new_element
> ```

which I cannot easily avoid as far as I know Keras

Answer (score 1):

I asked ChatGPT, and, to my surprise (due to previous experience), it solved my question correctly, as far as I can say at the moment, but I am open for comments.
Apparently this works:

```
class Autoencoder(Model):
def __init__(self, latent_dim, shape):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.shape = shape
    self.ht = 2
    self.buffer = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(shape[0], shape[1] * self.ht), dtype=tf.float32))

    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(int(shape[0] * shape[1] * 1.5), activation='swish'),
        layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='swish'),
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(int(shape[0] * shape[1] * 1.5), activation='swish'),
        layers.Dense(tf.math.reduce_prod(shape), activation='sigmoid'),
        layers.Reshape(shape)
    ])

def update_buffer(self, new_element):
    n = self.shape[1]
    self.buffer[:, n:].assign(self.buffer[:, :-n])
    self.buffer[:, :n].assign(new_element)

def call(self, x):
    decoded = []
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        buffer_tensor = self.buffer
        xin = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat((x[i, :, :], buffer_tensor), axis=1), axis=0)
        encoded = self.encoder(xin)
        buffer_reshaped = tf.reshape(buffer_tensor, [1, self.buffer.shape[0] * self.buffer.shape[1]])
        decin = tf.concat([encoded, buffer_reshaped], axis=1)
        y = self.decoder(decin)
        decoded.append(y)                
        self.update_buffer(tf.squeeze(y))
        
    out = tf.squeeze(tf.convert_to_tensor(decoded))
    return out
```

I tried something similar, but got the assignment in the update_buffer function wrong apparently!